# Moving data from one table to another SQL Server primary key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if it is possible to move all rows of data from one table to another, that match a certain query?

For example, I need to move all table rows from Table1 to Table2 so that they will no longer appear in Table1.

I'm using SQL Server 2017 (Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU13) (KB4466404) - 14.0.3048.4 (X64)   Nov 30 2018 12:57:58   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS)) 
and Management Studio 17.8.1.

I have a table1 that has three columns

```
SID (PK), ID_NAME (FK), AREA
```

All are of `INT` datatype.

Problem is that I have primary key on the `sid` column and all attempts to move data from `Table1` to `Table2` fails - because of primary key constraint.

What is best beginner's approach?

I have tried SQL server Import / Export wizard (export to another table) from SSMS abut always fails with error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__REN_PROS__64A186121EB5F6A0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.RENPRO'. The duplicate key value is (28477872).

I have also tried via query (as found in tutorials):

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (<columns>)
    SELECT <columns>
    FROM Table1
    WHERE <condition>;

DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE <condition>;

COMMIT;
```

And different variations of `NOCHECK CONSTRAINT` for the `SID` column.

But error is always the same.

Comment: You are trying to insert a duplicate value in a Primary key column, which is not allowed.   What do you want to have happen instead?  It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Fefox, please add the details to your question on how you are moving the data from one table to another. If it's by query, add the query. If it's using some other way, please add the details to your question. Without that there isn't much we can help you with.

Comment: Added in question example of code. My problem is that I would like to MOVE data not duplicate it. Please provide a working example for this or at lest direction of correct operation for this. Still new to MSSQL.

Comment: No one can provide a working example until you explain what is happening. Are there primary keys on both tables? If so then you must be trying to insert records that already exist. A primary key implies that you don't want duplicates in your table. Is that the case? You could always drop the primary key but then you'll get duplicates.